# MS access not refreshing form when selecting new record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I built an Access form and I am trying to hide some of the objects.

I have a dropdown list and all the data are updated based on the name I selected from the dropdown list. All the hidden objects are working fine when I first load the form. I click on the "Show" check box, and all the object controls load fine. I then save the record and select a new one from the dropdown list, however, all the hidden objects are still showing on the new record.

I would like to be able to hide them every time I select the new record from the dropdown list. How would I do this?

Comment: Use the `OnCurrent` event to hide the objects every time a new record is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Sub that hides all your objects.  Then, on the AfterUpdate event of the dropdown list, call that Sub.  Something like:

```
Private Sub HideObjects()
  Me.Object1.Visible = False
  Me.Object2.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Then, in the AfterUpdate event of MyDropdownList, you'd have this:

```
Private Sub MyDropdownList_AfterUpdate()
  Call HideObjects
End Sub
```